# Swing  работа с bat.

Tags: bat, java, swing

Есть приложение на свинге, у него есть вебстарт из *.bat Приложение запрашивает логин и пароль при запуске, Как научить приложение логиниться?

Понятно что в батник нужно дописать параметры логина и пароля, а вот как реализовать заполнение полей при запуске приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если передаете логин и пароль как параметры коммандной строки, то их можно получить в самой программе, у метода main же есть параметр args, вот там и будут храниться переданные значения